# Multiuser connections with access

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new in Microsoft access and apologies for asking any incorrect question.

I have a Excel VBA tool which is connected with Access. I just wanted to know as to how to handle the situation if multi user updating same recordset. Can we halt/wait till the recordset get closed by other user without letting the user know about background activities.

Below coding is being used by me.

```
Dim Acon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    With Acon
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + myFileNameDir
        .Open
    End With

With Rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = Acon
    .Source = "Select * from Sheet1"
     .Open
End With

With Rs
  Rs.MoveFirst
  While Not Rs.EOF
    .Fields![status] = "Refresher"
    .Fields![Reason for Refresh Training] = "Refresher-" & myValuec
    Rs.MoveNext
  Wend
End With
```

Comment: Not a comment on the question:  When adding code just paste all the code in, select the pasted code and click the Code Sample icon just above the text you entered - it's two curly brackets `{ }`.  You won't get the _enter code here_ text then.

Comment: The best way is to first check if file is updatable, if not use goto line # function.